# Why my docker file does not copy the HTML files?

Tags: docker, go, dockerfile

My directory is:

```
-Dockerfile
app/
    -main.go
media/
    /css
    /html
    /img
    /svg
```

Inside the html folder, I have subfolders to organise my `HTML` files, so the path to the `HTML` files is `media/html/*/*.html`

And I have my Dockerfile as follows:

```
FROM golang:alpine

# Set necessary environmet variables needed for our image
ENV GO111MODULE=on \
    CGO_ENABLED=0 \
    GOOS=linux \
    GOARCH=amd64

# Copy the code into the container
COPY media .

# Move to working directory /build
WORKDIR /build

# Copy the code from /app to the build folder into the container
COPY app .

# Configure the build (go.mod and go.sum are already copied with prior step)
RUN go mod download

# Build the application
RUN go build -o main .

WORKDIR /app

# Copy binary from build to main folder
RUN cp /build/main .

# Export necessary port
EXPOSE 8080

# Command to run when starting the container
CMD ["/app/main"]
```

and my main.go is:

```
package main

import (
    "net/http"

    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
)

func main() {
    // We create the instance for Gin
    r := gin.Default()

    // Path to the static files. /static is rendered in the HTML and /media is the link to the path to the  images, svg, css.. the static files
    r.StaticFS("/static", http.Dir("../media"))

    // Path to the HTML templates. * is a wildcard
    r.LoadHTMLGlob("../media/html/*/*.html")

    r.NoRoute(renderHome)
    // This get executed when the users gets into our website in the home domain ("/")
    r.GET("/", renderHome)
    r.Run(":8080")
}

func renderHome(c *gin.Context) {
    c.HTML(http.StatusOK, "my-html.html", gin.H{})
}
```

Problem is, I can run without problem my app in Golang with `go run main.go`, I can build the Docker image without problems, but on the moment to run a Docker container from the image, I got the error:
`panic: html/template: pattern matches no files: ../media/html/*/*.html`

The path is correct (since is also proven because I can run it in plain `go`) and it seems that Docker is not coping the files correctly, or at least not in the right directory. What is failing? The full simple project can be found [here](https://github.com/kiketordera/minimal-example)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`media` is a bad choice for a Docker folder, because a typical Linux container already has a `/media` folder.

But that's not the root cause.

The root cause is that `COPY media .` copies the *contents* of `media` folder to `/`. You probably want `COPY media/ /media/` if you want to preserve the `media` folder itself (or use `WORKDIR /media`).

As a debug tool, you can run your container with a shell as entrypoint to "look around" it without starting your app:

```
docker build . -t test
docker run -it --rm test sh
/app # ls /media
cdrom   floppy  usb                                                                                                                                             
/app # ls -R /html
/html:
website

/html/website:
my-html.html
```

As you can see your `media/html` folder is located at `/html`.

Some more notes:

It's a good idea to move `go mod download` to **before** `COPY app` so that the downloaded modules can be cached:

```
FROM golang:alpine

WORKDIR /build
COPY app/go.mod app/go.sum ./
RUN go mod download

COPY app .
RUN go build -o main .

WORKDIR /app
RUN cp /build/main .

COPY media /media/

EXPOSE 8080

CMD ["/app/main"]
```

As a next step you can look into two-stage builds to not depend on the `golang` image for running the compiled app (is only needed for building really).

Comment: Thanks you so much. You are right, the problem was the `COPY` instructions with the media, simply neeed to change  `COPY media .` ` to `COPY media /media/`. Thank you so much!!

Comment: Also grateful about all your explanation :)